# Check user keep staying at the same location

Tags: android, location

I am woring on an Android application which is sensitive to user location.

Once user stay at a location for a long time(20min for example), then we should do something accordingly (set the status of the nearest parking spot nearest as "busy"), and once he left that position set the status of the nearest parking spot nearest as "free".

Now I can get the user location for a registered `LocationListener`, however I have two problems:

1)How to track the user location to make it sure if he have style for the specified time at the same location?

I have thought to create a `Handler` and run a task to check the location:

```
private Location mLastLocation;
private Location mCurrentLocation;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable mLocationCalculateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
            if (!userLocationChanged()) {

            } else {

            }
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(mLocationCalculateRunnable,10000); //check every 10 seconds
    }

    private boolean userLocationChanged() {
        return getDistance(mCurrentLocation, mLastLocation) > 5;
    }
};
mHandler.postDelayed(mLocationCalculateRunnable,1000);


private void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = mCurrentLocation;
    mCurrentLocation = location;
}
```

But I can not continue to check the location and the time.

2)The app should run even if user click the `back` key to go back to the home screen, and the screen may get off, even the cpu may be go to sleep.

If so, I may not get the new location, and the handler may be stopped also.

I wonder my location check idea is proper and how to keep the app running at any suitation?

BTW,I can not access the google related services.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use defines to set proper updating for the `LocationManager`. These defines are minimum time and distance that is required to update position of user.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
```

2) Run `Service` that will work at background.

Small code example:

```
public class GPSservice extends Service implements LocationListener {


    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 2;

    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 1;

    double latitude, longitude;

    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location;

    protected LocationManager locationManager;


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        getLocation();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        new LocationReceiver(location, getApplicationContext());
    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                Log.d("Network", "OFF");
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "ON");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "ON");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that mean the service can never be stopped? And it seems that I have to put the location listener and the action(do something according to the location) at the service too?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html you can run services on the background of the app and user will be not enable to switch of him even when he will kill the app.